# [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]TDS buffer length too large exception

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, odbc

I am receiving the following exception in Java 1.7 when trying to establish an ODBC connection to a SQL database. I have searched all over the net for a solution, but I can only find descriptions of the problem without any Java solution. My connection string is as follows:

```
try {
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Connect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    r = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={SQL Server};SERVER=sql4.sqldatabase.com;PORT=3306;DATABASE=sql457564;UID=username;PWD=******");


} catch (SQLException ex) {
    System.err.println("Error in connection");
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The exception I receive is:

```
 java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]TDS buffer length too large
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6956)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7113)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(JdbcOdbc.java:3072)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:323)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:174)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:233)
```

Any help will be appreciated! 
Thanks